# checking network status before activity launches

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to add a feature that when a user clicks on a button that takes you to a website it should notify that you are not currently connected or no network connection available.  At the moment i have this code but it seems to just take me directly to the website (offline can't connect) but displays no information?

here is my code:

```
next7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

    }
  });
}
public void  checkNetworkStatus(){

    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
     this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

     final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
     connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

     final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
     connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

     if( wifi.isAvailable() ){

     Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     else if( mobile.isAvailable() ){

     Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     else
     {

         Toast.makeText(this, "No Network " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it like this

```
public boolean checkNetworkStatus() {
    boolean isConected = false;
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
        isConected = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
        isConected = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return isConected;
}
```

and

```
if(checkNetworkStatus())
    {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
    else{
        //No internet
    }
```